# Parse JSON to Java Object using GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, jenkins, gson

I am trying to map a json document from the jenkins API to my own java objects. The json document looks as follows:

```
{
    "assignedLabels": [
        {}
    ],
    "mode": "EXCLUSIVE",
    "nodeDescription": "Jenkins Master-Knoten",
    "nodeName": "",
    "numExecutors": 2,
    "description": null,
    "jobs": [
        {
            "name": "Job 1",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/job/Job1/",
            "color": "disabled"
        },
        {
            "name": "Job 2",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/job/Job2/",
            "color": "blue"
        }
    ],
    "overallLoad": {},
    "primaryView": {
        "name": "Alle",
        "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/"
    },
    "quietingDown": false,
    "slaveAgentPort": 0,
    "unlabeledLoad": {},
    "useCrumbs": false,
    "useSecurity": true,
    "views": [
        {
            "name": "Selection",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/view/-All%Selection/"
        },
        {
            "name": "All",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/"
        }
    ]
}
```

My java model looks like this:

```
public class JenkinsServer {
    private List<String> assignedLabels;
    private String url;

    private String mode;
    private String nodeName;
    private String nodeDescription;
    private String description;

    private boolean useSecurity;
    private boolean quietingDown;

    private JenkinsServerView primaryView;
    private List<JenkinsServerView> views;
    private List<JenkinsJob> jobs;

    // getters & setters
}
```

What I am doing now is I call

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JenkinsServer server = gson.fromJson( reader, JenkinsServer.class );
```

But I receive this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 6 column 5
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
```

I've been searching the internet for a solution but could not figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe you guys know :-)

Comment: Well one thing I see is that the assignedLabels in your code is a list of String while in the data it is an array with an empty object. I suggest you don't try to parse the entire file in one go but rather keep on adding more properties to the file and the Java objects; doing it iteratively makes it easier to know where there is a mismatch in the datastructure.

Comment: Refer this example. It may help you. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gimby mentioned in the comment, the problem is in your json data.

**Solution1:**

As `assignedLabels` is an array of strings with empty values, one option is to change the json data without curly braces as follows:

```
"assignedLabels": []
```

**Solution2:**

add `transient` keyword to the variable in java class

```
private transient List<String> assignedLabels;
```

**Solution3:**

the last and clumsy way to achieve is to add `@Expose` annotation to the all the variables that you want to parse in your java class

```
public class JenkinsServer {
    private List<String> assignedLabels;

    @Expose
    private String url;

    @Expose
    private String mode;

    @Expose
    private String nodeName;

    @Expose
    private String nodeDescription;

    @Expose
    private String description;

    @Expose
    private boolean useSecurity;

    @Expose
    private boolean quietingDown;

    @Expose
    private JenkinsServerView primaryView;

    @Expose
    private List<JenkinsServerView> views;

    @Expose
    private List<JenkinsJob> jobs;

    // getters & setters methods
}
```

and then add the parsing logic to parse your json string to corresponding java object as follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();      
JenkinsServer server = gson.fromJson(reader, JenkinsServer.class);
```